# Add Querystring from asp.net code behind not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string

```
  Response.Redirect("~/CustomList.aspx?id="+Data.Item1+"&type="+Data.Item2);
```

I am adding this from Codebehind Asp.net

However it isn't working

**Getting this Error**

**This page can't be displayed**

•Make sure the web address `http://localhost:51955` is correct.

•Look for the page with your search engine.

•Refresh the page in a few minutes.

Comment: Could your assign URL to variable and see its value? It will help you to debug the problem.

Comment: ~/CustomList.aspx?id=2&type=next get the following url

Comment: what is the url you see on your browser..???

Comment: http://localhost:51955/CustomList.aspx?id=1&type=next

Comment: Make sure the path is correct and do you get the same output in other browser? What browser are you testing with now?

Comment: i have tested in chrome , ie and firefox doesn't work for me

Comment: stop the running project, and stop the asp.net IIS port ICON at right hand side below corener & restart the debugging.

Comment: what is the type of the object [Data.Item1 and Data.Item2] ?

Answer (score 1):

Could you try something like this ?

```
 string parameter1 = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Data.Item1)
 string parameter2 =  HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Data.Item2)

 Response.Redirect("~/CustomList.aspx?id="+parameter1 +"&type="+parameter2 );
```

**And make sure that page is in the root of your project, is this page is in another project, you will need to change the port in the URL. Localhost:port/CustomList.aspx**